# Visual Basic code- Having trouble displaying the Total. New to VB

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I have to write a program that calculates costs for a catering company. i have that part down, but whats stumping me is I have trouble displaying the total. What also is stumping me is that i have to make a summary button that adds everything up into a grand total from the previous calculations and display it in a message box. displaying and calculations aren't really my issues, but getting the data to calculate is. 
Thank you

HERE's the code.

```
Const decPRIME_RIB As Decimal = 25.95D
Const decCHICKEN As Decimal = 18.95D
Const decPASTA As Decimal = 12.95D
Const decOPEN_BAR As Decimal = 25D
Const decWINE As Decimal = 8D
Const decBEER As Decimal = 10D

'Declare module-level variables for summary information.
Private TotalDollar As Decimal
Private AmountDue As Decimal
Private SubTotalDecimal As Decimal
Private TotalDecimal As Decimal
Private Guest As Integer
Private EventCountInteger As Integer

Private Sub CalcBtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CalcBtn.Click
    ' Calculate and display the current amounts and add to totals.
    Dim FoodChoiceDecimal As Decimal
    Dim OpenBarDecimal As Decimal
    Dim WineDecimal As Decimal
    Dim DrinksDecimal As Decimal

    ' Find the price.
    If PrimeRB.Checked Then
        FoodChoiceDecimal = decPRIME_RIB
    ElseIf ChickRB.Checked Then
        FoodChoiceDecimal = decCHICKEN
    ElseIf PastaRB.Checked Then
        FoodChoiceDecimal = decPASTA
    End If

    If OpenCB.Checked Then
        OpenBarDecimal = decOPEN_BAR
    End If
    If WineCB.Checked Then
        WineDecimal = decWINE
    End If

    'Multiply price by number of guest and drink selection.
    Try
        DrinksDecimal = (OpenBarDecimal + WineDecimal)
        AmountDue = (FoodChoiceDecimal + DrinksDecimal) * Guest


        ' display totals.
        TotalLbl.Text = TotalLbl.ToString("C")

        ' Allow change for new event.
        OpenCB.Enabled = False
        WineCB.Enabled = False
        ClearBtn.Enabled = True
        SummaryBtn.Enabled = True

    Catch NumberOfGuestsException As FormatException
        MessageBox.Show("Number of Guests must be Numeric", _
        "Data entry Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, _
        MessageBoxIcon.Information)



    End Try
End Sub


Private Sub SummaryBtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SummaryBtn.Click
    ' Calculate total dollar amounts and number of events.

    Dim MessageString As String
    If EventCountInteger > 0 Then
        ' Calculate the summary sales totals.
        TotalDollar += AmountDue

        'Concatenate the message string.
        MessageString = "Number of Events:" & EventCountInteger.ToString() _
        & Environment.NewLine & Environment.NewLine _
        & "Total Sales: " & TotalDollar.ToString("C")
        MessageBox.Show(MessageString, "Sales Summary", _
        MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
    End If
```

Comment: `TotalLbl.Text = AmountDue.ToString("C")`

Comment: Why is this marked java and c++?

Comment: Does this have anything at all to do with C++?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I fixed the tags. OP is a new user, don't just markdown a question because of a silly mistake. Instead edit the question to correct the mis-tagging leave a comment about how to do better and move on. The question itself is valid, even if it's not clearly explained.

Comment: Please review the [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) page. There are several variables that are being used in the two subs you posted which appear that they are being modified outside of the the code posted. For example, you have delclared `EventCountInteger` as a private int32, but I don't see where a value was assigned to it meaning that the `If EventCountInteger > 0 Then` block will always evaluate to false because the default value of an Integer is 0.

Comment: sorry i didn't know I'm new to this